# How to rename files in bash to increase number in name?

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I have a few thousand files named as follows:

```
Cyprinus_carpio_600_nanopore_trim_reads.fasta                
Cyprinus_carpio_700_nanopore_trim_reads.fasta               
Cyprinus_carpio_800_nanopore_trim_reads.fasta                
Cyprinus_carpio_900_nanopore_trim_reads.fasta 
Vibrio_cholerae_3900_nanopore_trim_reads.fasta
```

for 80 variations of the first two words (80 different species), i would like to rename all of these files such that the number is increased by 100 - for example:

```
Vibrio_cholerae_3900_nanopore_trim_reads.fasta
```

would become

```
Vibrio_cholerae_4000_nanopore_trim_reads.fasta
```

or

```
Cyprinus_carpio_300_nanopore_trim_reads.fasta
```

would become

```
Cyprinus_carpio_400_nanopore_trim_reads.fasta
```

Unfortunately I can't work out how to get to rename them, i've had some luck with following the solutions on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40523/rename-files-by-incrementing-a-number-within-the-filename

But i can't get it to work for the inside of the name, i'm running on Ubuntu 18.04 if that helps

Comment: Is there just one number embedded within the filename? Or might there be more? Is it always the 3rd part, or might it be elsewhere?

Comment: Hi, it's always in the same position, and only ever one number in the filename, thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can get hold of the Perl-flavoured version of `rename`, that is simple like this:

```
rename -n 's/(\d+)/$1 + 100/e' *fasta
```

**Sample Output**

```
'Ciprianus_maximus_11_fred.fasta' would be renamed to 'Ciprianus_maximus_111_fred.fasta'
'Ciprianus_maximus_300_fred.fasta' would be renamed to 'Ciprianus_maximus_400_fred.fasta'
'Ciprianus_maximus_3900_fred.fasta' would be renamed to 'Ciprianus_maximus_4000_fred.fasta'
```

If you can't read Perl, that says... *"Do a single substitution as follows. Wherever you see a bunch of digits next to each other in a row (`\d+`), remember them (because I put that in parentheses), and then replace them with the evaluated expression of that bunch of digits (`$1`) plus 100."*.

Remove the `-n` if the dry-run looks correct. The only *"tricky part"* is the use of `e` at the end of the substitution which means **evaluate** the expression in the substitution - or I call it a *"calculated replacement"*.

Comment: This seems good, the only problem i'm encountering is that because it's incremental steps, I get the following problem: Zygosaccharomyces_rouxii_3000_nanopore_trim_reads.fasta not renamed: Zygosaccharomyces_rouxii_3100_nanopore_trim_reads.fasta already exists

Comment: Also note, there are two common executables named `rename`. If you have the one provided by the `util-linux` package, you will not have the `-n` option.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, thank you. That is why I said *"the Perl flavoured"* one! If you happen to know the correct package, maybe you'd care to add it please? Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure how all your files are actually named. Maybe you could add 105 to each then subtract 5 so they don't clash? Do it on a spare **copy** of your files.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, unfortunately it is distribution dependent, for instance Archlinux provides a `perl-rename` package, Debian provides it as the `rename` package, but openSuSE has it bundled in some esoteric perl package that isn't readily apparent. Best advise is `rename -h` first `:)`

Comment: and if you want to add text beside your numbers, you can use `s/(\d+)/"blabla".($1+100)/e`

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one number in your string then below two line of code should provide help you resolve your issue

```
filename="Vibrio_cholerae_3900_nanopore_trim_reads.fasta"
var=$(echo $filename | grep -oP '\d+')
echo ${filename/${var}/$((var+100))}
```

Instead of echoing the changed file name, you can take it into a variable and use `mv` command to rename it

Comment: Probably better to use `+` instead of `*` for the `grep` as some versions don't use `*`

Comment: @I'L'l. Updated me answer

Answer (score 1):

Considering the filename conflicts in the increasing order, I first thought of reversing the order but there still remains the possibility of conflicts in the alphabetical (standard) sort due to the difference to the numerical sort.
Then how about a two-step solution: in the 1st step, an escape character (or whatever character which does not appear in the filename) is inserted in the filename and it is removed in the 2nd step.

```
#!/bin/bash

esc=$'\033' # ESC character

# 1st pass: increase the number by 100 and insert a ESC before it
for f in *.fasta; do
    num=${f//[^0-9]/}
    num2=$((num + 100))
    f2=${f/$num/$esc$num2}
    mv "$f" "$f2"
done

# 2nd pass: remove the ESC from the filename
for f in *.fasta; do
    f2=${f/$esc/}
    mv "$f" "$f2"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark's perl-rename solution looks great but you should apply it twice with a bump of 50 to avoid name conflict. If you can't find this flavor of rename you could try my rene.py (https://rene-file-renamer.sourceforge.io) for which the command would be (also applied twice) `rene *_*_*_*   *_*_?_*  B/50`. rene would be a little easier because it automatically shows you the changes and asks whether you want to make them and it has an undo if you change your mind.