# Having trouble arranging files into directories

Tags: linux, bash

I am attempting to organise text files of name f##.txt (#being a digit 0-9) into directories such that they end up as d#/f#.txt.

```
#! /bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                

for i in {0..9} ;
do
    mkdir -p "$1/d$i "
    for j in {0..9};
    do
    FILE= "/$1/f$i$j.txt"
        if [ -f FILE ];
        then
            echo 'Moving!'
            mv "/$1/f$i$j.txt" "/$1/d$i/f$j.txt"
        fi
    done
done
```

The code above is what I have so far but I keep getting the error:

```
CO1101/OSN2/q4-arrange.sh: line 8: /test/f00.txt: No such file or directory
```

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

The test directory is inside the current working directory

Comment: Do there exist a directory `/test`? I.e. the directory `test` in the ***root***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pref=f ext=txt
for f in "$pref"[0-9][0-9]."$ext"; do
    num=${f#"$pref"} num=${num%."$ext"}
    dir=d${num%?} file=$pref${num#?}.$ext

    [[ -d $dir ]] || mkdir -- "$dir" || exit 1
    mv -- "$f" "$dir/$file"
done
```

---

**Test run:**

```
$ tree
.
├── f11.txt
├── f14.txt
├── f28.txt
├── f30.txt
└── script
$ ./script
$ tree
.
├── d1
│   ├── f1.txt
│   └── f4.txt
├── d2
│   └── f8.txt
├── d3
│   └── f0.txt
└── script
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a space between FILE= and "/$1/f$i$j.txt".  Try removing the space and see what happens.  Bash does not like spaces in variable assignments (i.e. around the equal sign).

Hope this helps.

Comment: No more error now but the if statement doesn't seem to be working, the file f48.txt exists but isn't moved.

Comment: You are just testing for the string FILE, not for what the variable FILE is assigned to.

Comment: Should it be: if [ -f $FILE ];

Comment: Yes.  You want to validate that the file defined in the FILE variable exists.  Just like your i and j variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `rename` utility - also known as **Perl rename**, you can use this rather succinct command:

```
rename --dry-run -p 's|f([0-9])([0-9])|d$1/f$2|' *txt
```

**Sample Output**

```
'f11.txt' would be renamed to 'd1/f1.txt'
'f14.txt' would be renamed to 'd1/f4.txt'
'f28.txt' would be renamed to 'd2/f8.txt'
'f30.txt' would be renamed to 'd3/f0.txt'
```

---

See **comments** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52641048/2836621) on how the package may be called in various distros.

---

If anyone is on **macOS**, you can install it with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install rename
```