# Howto rename bunch of filenames which are calculated

Tags: bash, awk, sed, find, mv

I want rename bunch of filenames. The rename is based on the calculation of the filename. That means the actual filename + 3600 = new filename.
Important is that the underscore in the pid files have to stay.

Thanks in advance!

My system is Debian Stretch.

Actual Filename:

```
134235.error
134235_.pid
134235.tiff


13893.error
13893_.pid
13893.tiff

1.error
1_.pid
1.tiff
```

Rename to:

```
137835.error
137835_.pid
137835.tiff


17493.error
17493_.pid
17493.tiff

3601.error
3601_.pid
3601.tiff
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640820/how-to-rename-files-in-bash-to-increase-number-in-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Perl's standalone `rename` command. Some distributions call it `prename`.

```
rename -n 's/(\d+)(.+)/${\($1+3600)}$2/' *
```

If everything looks fine, remove `-n`.

Answer (score 3):

```
for fname in *; do
   echo mv -- "$fname" "${fname/*[[:digit:]]/$((${fname%%[^[:digit:]]*}+3600))}"
done
```

If everything looks ok, remove `echo`.