# Sequential renaming in bash

Tags: linux, bash, rename, filenames

I have files named

```
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt .... 1000.txt.
```

I want to rename them using shell so they could look like:

```
5.txt 6.txt 7.txt...1005.txt.
```

Is there any way to achieve this in bash?

Comment: `Is there any way to achieve this in bash?` Yes, there is - list all files, extract the number, sort reverse numericaly on numbers, then for each filename, extract the number, increase the number by 5, move the file, repeat.

Comment: This example shows you how to add 100 to the number in a filename https://stackoverflow.com/a/52641048/2836621 If you do that directly, the numbers will clash (i.e. you will clash with `5.txt` when you rename `1.txt`), so you could rename files first to say `1.xxx`, `2.xxx` to avoid the clash.

Comment: Why `1005.txt`? Shouldn't it have been `1004.txt`?

Comment: `mkdir orig && mv *.txt orig/ && mv orig/*[^0-9]*.txt . && rename 's|.*/(\d+)|4+$1|e' orig/* && rmdir orig`

Comment: Please also check [ask].

Answer (score -1):

For your bulk renaming:

```bash
ls -rv | while read x
do
  n=$(echo "$x" | grep -Po '\d+')
  mv "$x" $((n + 4)).txt
done
```

First part lists the files in reverse sorted order,

then for each filename in the while loop:

1. Extract number from the filename as `n`
2. Rename the file as "`(n + 4).txt`"